# Want to give access of new site from drive api, getting error "Sorry, an item is restricted in sharing."

Tags: google-sites, google-drive-realtime-api

We are using google drive api with node js to grant permission for user scope, it is working fine for any folder in drive with below scope

drive.permissions.create({
                        fileId: mysiteUrl,
                        sendNotificationEmail: false,
                        resource: {
                            role: 'reader',
                            type: 'user',
                            emailAddress: EmailIdofUser,
                        }
                    }, (error, permissionResponse) => {
                        if (error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        } else {
                            res.send("drive access granted");
                       }
                    });

When we use new google sites to provide the access, it gives an error "Sorry, an item is restricted in sharing.".

Can you please guide what should be correct scope file?

Regards,
Anubhav.

Comment: @Anubhav, can you explain a) what you mean by "use new google sites to provide the access", as it is not clear from your question what you are trying to do; and b) what do you mean by "with node js" are you referring to a Node.js program running outside google cloud? c) have you set-up the new Google Site as an Intranet - for use only by users with a google account, or for anyone on the Internet? If you answer these questions people will stand a better chance of helping.

Comment: @Burke We have created a private google site and want to share this with specific people, How to give provide shared access of this site with people using Node.js program?

Comment: @Anubhav, I'm afraid I'm still unable to see the connection between a (presumably) external Node.js program, new Google Sites, and the Google Drive API. Can you explain further? Also, in case you are not aware, new Google Sites does not yet have an API, as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/sites/); could this be your problem?